# jQuery Iframe content with hasClass

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access all content under iframe using jQuery.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hitub/KnTPp/)

and I am using this jquery

```
res=$('#twittericon').find('body').hasClass('ready');
alert(res);
```

This is showing result false to me. it must show true, 
Anybody tell me where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It's really hard to access content of iframe. Because the owner of i frame is like third party. We have tried before but failed!! Hope somebody here to answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't access the iframe with Javascript. Your iframe's source is platform.twitter.com, which is a different domain to that of your code.

The only way you can modify the twitter icon is to use the options that twitter explicitly expose as arguments in the URL.